# Exclusion of cases for one predictor variable in SPSS?

Tags: multiple-regression, spss, categorical-encoding

I am running a multiple regression analysis based on a survey I conducted with teachers. I am planning to use teacher gender as one of my predictor variables. The survey from which my data originate included five response options - male, female, genderqueer/gender non-conforming, prefer not to answer, prefer to self-describe. No one chose "prefer to self-describe." Given the small number of individuals who responded genderqueer/gender non-conforming (n=2) and prefer not to answer (n=1), I am going to include only male (n=28) and female (n=298) in my analyses. Right now I have four dummy variables to represent the gender variable (i.e., male, female, genderqueer/non-conforming, prefer not to answer).

What is the best way to exclude the 3 cases that did not respond male or female? Is there a way to do this using the dummy variables I've created? Using the "select cases" command would exclude those 3 participants from ALL predictor variables in the regression equation, not just the gender variable, correct? Would it be better to turn gender into a dichotomous variable (with 0 = male, 1 = female) and the other three response options defined as missing values?

Comment: I guess an answer could depend on your analysis goals. So what is it?

Comment: I am studying predictors of teachers' responses to student bullying behavior for my dissertation study. I am currently conducting some initial multiple regression analyses. As mentioned, teacher gender is one of my predictor variables. Other predictors are both continuous (e.g., teachers' ratings of self-efficacy) and categorical (e.g., presence of anti-bullying policy at school). Based on the literature, one analysis goal is to determine whether teacher gender significantly predicts responses to student bullying (e.g., one outcome variable is likelihood of intervening in a bullying incident).

Comment: PLease add new information as an edit to the post, and not only in comments. Not everybody reads comments ...